# Laptop not starting up after trip - lights are on but it's dead

Tags: laptop, boot, hardware-failure, emachines

I have an eMachines E525 that I just brought when traveling by airplane. After arriving the computer won't start.

The LEDs showing the computer has power light up when I turn it on. The fan operates for just a few seconds, then the computer turns 100% silent and nothing is shown on the monitor.

I'm thinking something got loose, but what could it be? I've opened up stationary computers hundreds of times, but actually never a laptop. Not sure about what to do. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bad power supply.  Does this happen with the power cord plugged in?  Are you traveling to a country with a different voltage by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately, it happens both when I have the cable plugged in and when it's not. I've been where I am before without having a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reseting the laptop, take the battery off the back, remove adaptor, remove hard drive, take memory out, hold the power button down for 15 secs, resit one bank of memory, plug in the adaptor, press the power button and see if comes on, if it does pull the adaptor out before it starts loading and resit the second bank of memory.  If still no display, try an external monitor and see if that works, if so the screen will need replaced.  Other than that, remove all memory and turn on, if it does not beep, your mainboard and/or CPU is damaged, if it does beep, you could have bad memory.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Removed the screws, touched the HDD etc, then it came back on. I guess the parts where just a bit loose!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either the motherboard or the motherboard is not getting enough power.

I think it's time for a new laptop. Unless you can detect soldering issues and can solder yourself, it's pretty much done.

Comment: @jawa yay for the English major! :)